# how to pass my prompt text as query string to controller method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, query-string

In my view page i have  a prompt when i write something i need to store back in variable later i want to pass it controller method . I am unable to pass the value to controller ?

My code :

```
 var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val()

 oTable.makeEditable({

     "sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/"?start=reason , //here i am having problem passing var reason to "/HOME/deletedata/"
```

So i can access the query string via request.querystring["start"] and use the content ?

Any alternate way also appreciated

Regards

Comment: try this `"sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/?start="+reason ,`

Comment: yes bingo .! please make it as answer so i can mark it as answer . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`"sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData/?start="+reason ,`